# How to parse xls file containing multiple sheets, within 50MB of memory, in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls, chunks, memory-efficient

I have used POI and Jexcel. POI uses as much memory as the file size and Jexcel take a lot of memory while loading a workbook.
My requirement is to process an xls file in chunks, so as to reduce the memory consumption.

Comment: Define "process in chunks".  What is a "chunk"?

Comment: _When the sheets are independent._ The xlsx file is just zip with XML files and such. Use a java zip filesystem (`jar:file:/...`). The content XML could be split by a simple BufferedReader on the zip for every sheet, and generate a new xlsx.

Comment: "to process an xls file in chunks": This is not possible since all kind of `Excel` files have a internal file system separated into workbook part, styles part, shared strings part and sheets parts. So there is no way to avoid processing the whole `Excel` file as one unit. But `apache poi` provides a event driven approach for [HSSF](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api) as well as for [XSSF](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api).

Comment: @Stephen C Chunks means I don't have to load the whole file in the memory, I could process it in small parts.

Comment: @ Joop Eggen I want to parse xls and not xlsx.

Comment: @ Axel Richter I used HSSF, but the memory usage was same as the file size. If the file size is 50MB, then memory usage is also, on average 50MB.

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI provides a SAX like API to access Excel documents.

See [Apache POI Event API](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api):

> The event API is newer than the User API. [...] The advantage provided is that you can read an XLS with a
>   relatively small memory footprint.

Comment: The `HSSF` event API has nothing to do with `SAX` since `SAX` is **S**imple **A**PI for **X**ML and `HSSF` is not `XML` but binary file format `BIFF`.

Comment: @Axel Richter: I know what SAX is. The event API is a SAX *like* API. See the [POI Spreadsheet API Feature Summary](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/). They compare the Excel parsing with XML parsing. There is an API similar to XML DOM which loads the whole document in memory. And an API similar to SAX which doesn't need the whole document in memory.

Comment: Could you please name the api which works same as xml parser.

Comment: @somey: There is a link in my answer

Comment: Quoting from the linked page: *" If you're merely reading spreadsheet data, then use the eventmodel api in either the org.apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel package, or the org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel package, depending on your file format."*